# Error while generating release apk android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

below is the code for generating ABC and XYZ flavors .

```
 productFlavors {
        ABC{
            applicationId 'com.domainName.ABC'
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        XYZ{
            minSdkVersion 16
            applicationId 'com.domainName.XYZ'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
    }

        buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'

    }
    release {


        applicationIdSuffix '.release'

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

It is generating debug apks successfully but giving below error while generating release apks

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:handleABCReleaseMicroApk'.
> The main and the micro apps do not have the same package name.
```

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski Ihave tried this but it does not work for me